# ASP.NET DataAdapter Query Not Valid While The Query Works

Tags: asp.net, oracle, dataset, dataadapter

I started to use DataSet in my ASP.net web app like 6 months ago. It is a beautiful tool, allow me to rapidly develop MVC application without having to do all the dirty works in DB connection/queries.

But today I faced some weird problem. It started with this query:

`select a.MR_PART_CODE as PART_CODE,`

```
       b.PART_DESC as PART_DESC, 
       b.PM_MAD_CAT_CODE as CATEGORY, 
       c.MPC_MIN_QTY as CAT_SS, 
       a.MR_MAX_LEAD_TIME as LEAD_TIME, 
       a.MR_MAD as MAD, 
       ROUND((a.MR_MAD * a.MR_MAX_LEAD_TIME)) as CAL_SS, 
       greatest(ROUND((a.MR_MAD * a.MR_MAX_LEAD_TIME)),c.MPC_MIN_QTY) as SS,
       d.SOH as SOH, 
       d.SOO as SOO,
       (select sum(back_order) from STK_REQUEST where part_code=b.part_code) as BO,
       (d.SOH+a.MR_SOO) as AVAIL,
       ((d.SOH + a.MR_SOO)-greatest(ROUND((a.MR_MAD * a.MR_MAX_LEAD_TIME)),c.MPC_MIN_QTY)) as ROQ,
       (d.SOH - greatest(ROUND((a.MR_MAD * a.MR_MAX_LEAD_TIME)),c.MPC_MIN_QTY) ) as VAR,
       a.MR_REMARKS as REMARKS           
    from ROQ a, PART_MASTER b, MAD_PARTS_CATEGORY c, PART_STATS d
    where a.MR_PART_CODE = b.PART_CODE
    and d.PART_CODE = b.PART_CODE
    and b.PM_MAD_CAT_CODE = c.MPC_CAT_CODE
    and b.RETIRE_FLAG = 'N'
    and a.mr_year = (select max(mr_year) from roq)
    and a.mr_month = (select max(mr_month) from roq where mr_year= (select max(mr_year) from roq))
    and a.mr_period = (select max(mr_period) from roq where mr_month=(select max(mr_month) from roq where mr_year= (select max(mr_year) from roq)) and mr_year= (select max(mr_year) from roq))
    and     greatest(ROUND((a.MR_MAD * a.MR_MAX_LEAD_TIME)),c.MPC_MIN_QTY) > d.SOH`
```

The query ran fine in Toad for Oracle, but apparently it fails when I tried to setup as a new query in DataAdapter object. It says something like "Error in list of function arguments: SELECT not recognized" to this line:
`(select sum(back_order) from STK_REQUEST where part_code=b.part_code) as BO`

What did I do wrong?

FYI, the database is Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an exception from some ASP class trying to parse your SQL. There would be an ORA-xxxxx error number if the message came from Oracle.

You shouldn't put SQL like that in ASP. Create a view instead, perhaps it's ok then.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Do you mind explaining more why use View instead of normal SQL in asp.net data adapter?